# Update 10.10 server under VMWare

Tags: 10.10, server, command-line, updates

I'm using Ubuntu Server 10.10 under VMware Workstation 7.1.3 and I wonder how to update ubuntu server via terminal since I don't have any GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make system upgrades you need to type `sudo apt-get update` to get the information about new updates from your repository and to download and install the upgrades you need to type `sudo apt-get upgrade` .

If you want this in a single command you could just add `&&` like this:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

you need to type in your root passwd to be able to install updates.